# Soft key not appear while tapping on EditText which is inside listView and listView is in AleartBox

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-alertdialog

In my application customize Alear Box is there. In this alert box there is a customize ListView in which one TextView and one EditText is there. Every thing work fine and Alert Box coming on the screen perfectly.

But when I tap on Edit text to fill the characters into the Edit Text, Android Softkey on appearing. Therefore I am not able to insert and data into Edit Text.

My Code:-

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Population"
    android:onClick="getPopulation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**alert_box.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_view_resourse" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_view_resourse.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/district"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/population"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.exmp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private ArrayAdapter<Disrict> adapter;
private ArrayList<Disrict> disricts;
private ListView lView;
private Button add, cancel;
private AlertDialog dialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void getPopulation() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_box, null);
    lView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lView);
    add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
    cancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    disricts = new ArrayList<Disrict>();
    disricts.add(new Disrict(1, "Bangalore", 45.22));
    disricts.add(new Disrict(1, "Gulbarga", 22.22));
    adapter = new DistrictAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_view_resourse, disricts);
    lView.setAdapter(adapter);

    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Population");
    alert.setView(view);
    alert.setCancelable(false);

    dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.show();

}

public void getPopulation(View v){
    getPopulation();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:

        break;

    case R.id.cancel:
        dialog.dismiss();
        break;
    }
}
}
```

**Disrict**

```
package com.exmp;

public class Disrict {
private int id;
private String strDistrict;
private double population;
public Disrict(int id, String strDistrict, double population) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.strDistrict = strDistrict;
    this.population = population;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public String getStrDistrict() {
    return strDistrict;
}
public double getPopulation() {
    return population;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return strDistrict;
}
}
```

**DistrictAdapter**

```
package com.exmp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DistrictAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Disrict> {

private final Context context;
private final int rowResourceId;
private final ArrayList<Disrict> disricts;

public DistrictAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        ArrayList<Disrict> disricts) {
    super(context, resource, disricts);

    this.context = context;
    this.rowResourceId = resource;
    this.disricts = disricts;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Spinner spinnerPaymentType = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
    TextView textView  = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.district);
    textView.setText(disricts.get(position).getStrDistrict());

    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: did u get the solution ? please let me know if you got it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your listview

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems which help me.
It better to use dynamical views rather than ListView when you have e Focasable view inside of Cell
related links: 
[EditText inside ListView lost focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003715/edittext-inside-listview-lost-focus), 
[EditText inside ListView will not stay focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730610/edittext-inside-listview-will-not-stay-focused), 
[Android :EditText loses content on scroll in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328301/android-edittext-loses-content-on-scroll-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

```
 ettext.requestFocus();
                ettext.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        keyboard.showSoftInput(ettext, 0);
                    }
                },200);
```

Comment: http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-edittext-receives-focus/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810959/edittext-onclick-not-shows-virtual-keyboard